# netcat throughput low but iperf high

Tags: bandwidth

I was testing the throughput between two pcs, connected on the same router, one with 100mbps lan, the other with 54mbps wifi.

Here is the interesting part:

- using `nc`, I get **2.63MB/s** when sending from A to B (measured with `pv -r|nc ipB`)
- using `iperf`, I get **23MB/s** which is pretty much ok.

What could be wrong with `nc`?

The OS is ubuntu 11.04 for both.

Comment: I have a very similar question that you might find useful: [Measuring network throughput with netcat vs. CIFS/SMB transfer rates](http://serverfault.com/questions/211410/measuring-network-throughput-with-netcat-vs-cifs-smb-transfer-rates)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48399/fast-way-to-copy-a-large-file-on-a-lan

Answer (score 6):

The scale sound about right for NetCat not supporting TCP Windowing. If you do a tcpdump on the interface while the two benchmarks are running I'm guessing you'll see this pattern for NC:

1. Packet ->
2. <- Ack
3. Packet ->
4. <- Ack
5. Packet ->
6. <- Ack
7. Packet ->
8. <- Ack

And this pattern for IPerf:

1. Packet ->
2. Packet ->
3. Packet ->
4. Packet ->
5. Packet ->
6. Packet ->
7. <- Ack
8. Packet ->
9. Packet ->
10. Packet ->
11. Packet ->
12. Packet ->
13. Packet ->
14. <- Ack
15. Packet ->
16. Packet ->
17. Packet ->
18. Packet ->
19. Packet ->
20. Packet ->
21. <- Ack

By Windowing TCP segments you can get much higher throughputs since you don't have to wait for the Ack after every packet, only after every segment.

Comment: I can confirm I see the same issue on my 10g setup. `dd/netcat` is reports lower bandwidth as compared to `iperf`. `dd/netcat` report about 3Gb/s whereas `iperf` reports 9Gb/s.

Comment: Care to check if your guess is correct here? :)

Comment: My Windows 10 box using netcat was just sending 8KB packets with a TCP window size of only 8KB, resulting in awful performance over gigabit.  Happens in both nc and ncat, but SSH gives 90+ MB/sec between the same machines.  There is an old bug in windows sockets that causes this:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823764/slow-performance-occurs-when-you-copy-data-to-a-tcp-server-by-using-a

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `netcat`. With `iperf` I get

```
[  3] local 192.168.1.201 port 55610 connected with 192.168.1.200 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   394 MBytes  39.4 MBytes/sec
```

With `nc -l -p 1852 > /dev/null` and `cat /dev/zero | pv -r | nc 192.168.1.200 1852` I get

```
[  34MB/s]
```

(Fluctuates between 30 and 60.)

What data are you feeding `netcat`?

Answer (score 0):

Just because your wireless card is capable of 54mbs connections doesn't mean you are going to get that throughput. In particularly, it sounds like you have 802.11g which has an [Achilies heel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles_heal). As long as **every* wireless device it is talking to is also *g* it will go fast, but as soon as even one device that is only *b* speed capable, it has to use the lowest common denominator to talk to all devices.

You might try opening a terminal on the machine with wireless and running `iwconfig`. Look for the *Bit Rate=* field and see what speed you are actually connected at.

Answer (score 0):

Beware about iperf units. This is a common pitfall: iperf often display in Mbit/s instead of Mbyte/s.